# Bringing over only certain columns in LET & FILTER function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a LET & FILTER function used to use a drop down (green cell) and then it populates a report underneath based on data in sheet("Master")

You can see it's bringing in all the ("Master") sheet columns B:M in order and I don't need columns C:K

How can I change?

```
fRng,Master!B3:INDEX(Master!M:M,lr)
```

to only index and populate columns B, L, M into the sheet with the green drop down (the sheet with my LET formula)?

rest of formula:

```
=LET(
lr,COUNTA(Master!L:L),
fRng,Master!B3:INDEX(Master!M:M,lr),
criteriaRng1,Master!L3:INDEX(Master!L:L,lr),
criteriaRng2,Master!M3:INDEX(Master!M:M,lr),
FILTER(fRng,(criteriaRng1=Metrics!A1)* 
(criteriaRng2="Negotiating")))
```

value error after trying to add an array to specify columns:

[image]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Hey, I added that and I get a value error. I attached a photo of the data that i'm indexing at bottom of my post if that helps

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I also took a screenshot of the value error and the formula update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _LastRow, COUNTA(MASTER!L:L),
     _FRng, MASTER!B3:INDEX(MASTER!B:M,_LastRow,),
     _CriteriaRange1, MASTER!L3:INDEX(MASTER!L:L,_LastRow),
     _CriteriaRange2, MASTER!M3:INDEX(MASTER!M:M,_LastRow),
     _Output, FILTER(_FRng,(_CriteriaRange1="Dan")*(_CriteriaRange2="Negotiating")),
     INDEX(_Output,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_Output)),{1,11,12}))
```

---

Also the simplest one I can see is this, since you are already extracting the individual columns using the `_LastRow` variable for `_FRng`, `_CriteriaRange1` & `CriteriaRange2` then.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _LastRow, COUNTA(L:L),
     _FRng, B3:INDEX(B:B,_LastRow,),
     _CriteriaRange1, L3:INDEX(L:L,_LastRow),
     _CriteriaRange2, M3:INDEX(M:M,_LastRow),
     FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2,3},_FRng,_CriteriaRange1,_CriteriaRange2),(_CriteriaRange1="Dan")*(_CriteriaRange2="Negotiating")))
```

---

It is still working on my end even when the formula is entered in the other sheets, please refer the screenshots

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _LastRow, COUNTA(MASTER!L:L),
     _FRng, MASTER!B3:INDEX(MASTER!B:B,_LastRow),
     _CriteriaRange1, MASTER!L3:INDEX(MASTER!L:L,_LastRow),
     _CriteriaRange2, MASTER!M3:INDEX(MASTER!M:M,_LastRow),
     _Hstack, CHOOSE({1,2,3},_FRng,_CriteriaRange1,_CriteriaRange2),
     FILTER(_Hstack,(_CriteriaRange1=A1)*(_CriteriaRange2="Negotiating")))
```

---

Comment: Hey, so I specified before that a formula method like this is much easier than the initial PQ setup and I really only will be maxing out at 5000 rows. I did do the choose cols method and getting #NAME? error

Comment: and I tried using your top suggestion and I get a #VALUE error

Comment: so the #VALUE error sounds like it's on the right track, but not sure what could be causing that

Comment: Hey, are you able to try this by putting B:M columns like you have in a separate sheet called "Master" and the formula in a sheet called "Metrics" and then try writing the formula again? I am still getting a value error even after updating the ranges with the correct sheet name

Comment: Alright, but it works on my end, !

Comment: Hey, that worked (the bottom one) thank you!

Comment: @Kolev_I_N blessings, thanks =)

Comment: Hey, I had one last question. How would I wrap in a UNIQUE function in this so that it only returns unique values instead of duplicate rows?

Comment: @Kolev_I_N have you tried this yet? `UNIQUE(FILTER(_Hstack,(_CriteriaRange1=A1)*(_CriteriaRange2="Negotiating")))`

Comment: @Kolev_I_N btw this is the shorter one as far I can see: `=LET(
     _LastRow, COUNTA(MASTER!B:B),
     _FRng, MASTER!B3:INDEX(MASTER!B:M,_LastRow,),
     _Output, FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2,3},INDEX(_FRng,,1),INDEX(_FRng,,11),INDEX(_FRng,,12)),
           (INDEX(_FRng,,11)=A1)*(INDEX(_FRng,,12)="Negotiating")),
     UNIQUE(_Output))`

Comment: Instead of `Choose({1,2,3},Index(..` you could also use `CHOOSECOLS(_FRng,1,11,12)`

Comment: @P.b Sir, OP has mentioned they dont have access to `CHOOSECOLS()` I have mentioned earlier bt deleted later once they informed.

Comment: Alright, Gotcha